# index out of range when trying to load image url from json data

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to load data from NYTime Articles search API to an UITableView. I can load the text(headline, abstract) just fine but I have been having some trouble to load the image url, basically need to access nested json.

Here's the [JSON Data](https://pastebin.com/5kUwgBxd) using "pelosi" keyword and here's the [API doc](https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/overview)

Here's the models I have set up

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var docs = [Docs]()
    ...
}
class Docs: Mappable {
    ...
    var multimedia = [Multimedia]()
    var headline : Headline?
    ...
}
class Multimedia: Mappable {
    ...
    var url: String?
    ...
}
```

I pass the data to:

```
var docResult: [Docs] = []
```

here's my `numberOfRows` :

```
 return docResult.count
```

Tried to load the image into each cell using kingfisher but got Index out of range error :

```
var cellResponse: Docs!
let imgUrl = URL(string: "https://static01.nyt.com/\(cellResponse.multimedia[0].url)!")
docImg.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
```

The thing I'm trying to do is retrieve a single item (url of the first in the multimedia array). Can someone provide a solution for this ? Thanks !

EDIT: 
here's my `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.cellResponse = docResult[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: On which line do you get your error?

Comment: I got error on this: let imgUrl = ...

Comment: Thanks. So is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: If you get this crash in this line then `multimedia` is empty. You have to check that.

Comment: no the code I use to load the image is in a separate uitableviewcell class

Comment: Please don't guess, read the JSON. It contains clearly one empty multimedia array

Comment: @vadian my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this crash in this line then `multimedia` is empty. You have to check that

```
if let multimediaURL = cellResponse.multimedia.first?.url,
   let imgUrl = URL(string: "https://static01.nyt.com/\(multimediaURL)") {
       docImg.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
}
```